# Given $2$ opposite points of a square, find the other $2$.

Tags: geometry

> Let $a$ and $b$ be $2$ **real and strictly positive** numbers. The
>   points $B(a, 0)$ and $D(0, b)$ are $2$ *opposite* points of the square
>   $ABCD$. Find the other $2$ points.

This is what the information given would look like on a graph.

[image]

Where $B(a,0)$ can slide along the $Ox$ axis (but not at or to the left of $O(0,0)$ since $a$ is strictly positive) and $D(0, b)$ can slide along the $Oy$ axis (but not at or lower than $O(0,0)$ since $b$ is strictly positive).

So now we have to find the other $2$ points of the square $ABCD$ (I assume in terms of $a$ and $b$). This is what I tried:

Because $ABCD$ is a square I thought we should use the many special properties of the diagonals of a square. So the first thing I did was to find the equation of the line $d$ that passes through the diagonal $[DB]$. We know that this is a diagonal since the statement of the problem says that $B$ and $D$ are **opposite** points of the square. This is that line:

$$d: y = -\dfrac{b}{a}x + b$$

Then , we know that the diagonals intersect at their mid-points, so using the points $B(a, 0)$ and $D(0, b)$ of the diagonal, we can find the center of the square, $M$:

$$x_M = \dfrac{x_B + x_D}{2} = \dfrac{a + 0}{2} = \dfrac{a}{2}$$

$$y_M = \dfrac{y_B + y_D}{2} = \dfrac{0 + b}{2} = \dfrac{b}{2}$$

So we have that the intersection of the diagonals (center of the square) is:

$$M \bigg (\dfrac{a}{2}, \dfrac{b}{2} \bigg )$$

Then , knowing that the diagonals of a square are perpendicular, knowing the equation of the line of one of the diagonals and knowing that the point $M$ is on this other diagonal (since $M$ is on both of the diagonals), we can find the equation of the line on which the second diagonal is located. After some calculations I found this equation to be:

$$g : y = \dfrac{a}{b}x + \dfrac{b^2 - a^2}{2b}$$

Now our picture looks like this:[image]

And now all that is left is that we have to find the $2$ points $A$ and $C$ that are located on the blue line, $g$, such that $ABCD$ is a square. Because we have that $A \in g$ and $C \in g$, the $2$ points are:

$$A \bigg( x_A, \dfrac{a}{b}x_A + \dfrac{b^2-a^2}{2b} \bigg )$$

$$C \bigg( x_C, \dfrac{a}{b}x_C + \dfrac{b^2-a^2}{2b} \bigg )$$

And I am lost here. I can't find $x_A$ and $x_C$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. I tried equating segment lengths, finding those segment lengths using the general formula:

$$NM = \sqrt{(x_N - x_M)^2 + (y_N - y_M)^2}$$

for $2$ points $N(x_N, y_N)$ and $M(x_M, y_M)$. But that resulted in some monstrous calculations with a quadratic of $x_A$ **and** a bunch of $a's$ and $b's$.

So how can I find $A$ and $C$?

Comment: A circle centered at $M$ going through $D$ will go through all four points of the square you're looking for.

Comment: Something also to note that may help is the fact that $AC$ is orthogonal to $BD$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [an interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s5qby7qxt7) on Desmos that allows you to drag points $B$ and $D$ and watch how points $A$ and $C$ change.

While it might not be the quickest way to get there, you can certainly get the solution in the way that you were attempting - with your function $g$ and the distance function, as you were on track to do!

To solve the problem this way, just set up the two equations, and solve. You want the two points $X \in \{A, C\} = \{(x_A, y_A), (x_C, y_C)\}$ that satisfy two conditions. First, they lie along the line $g$, i.e.
\begin{align}
  y &= \frac{a}{b}x + \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2b}
\end{align}

Second, the distance from $B$ to $D$ is twice the distance from each $X$ to $M$, i.e.
\begin{align}
  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} &= 2 \sqrt{\left(x - \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y - \frac{b}{2}\right)^2}  \\ \Rightarrow
  a^2 + b^2 &= 4 \left(x - \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + 4 \left(y - \frac{b}{2}\right)^2  \\ \Rightarrow
  a^2 + b^2 &= \left(2x - a\right)^2 + \left(2y - b\right)^2
\end{align}

Substitute the value for $y$ from the first equation into the second, and solve for $x$. You need two points, but the equation is quadratic, so that's a hint that you're probably gonna be OK and end up with 2 possible solutions which are your two points.
\begin{align}
  a^2 + b^2 &= \left(2x - a\right)^2 + \left(2\left( \frac{a}{b}x + \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2b} \right) - b\right)^2 \\
  a^2 + b^2 &= \left(2x - a\right)^2 + \frac{a^2}{b^2} \left(2x - a\right)^2  \\
  a^2 + b^2 &= \frac{a^2 + b^2}{b^2} \left(2x - a\right)^2  \\
  b^2 &= \left(2x - a\right)^2  \Rightarrow
  \pm b = 2x - a
\end{align}
$$
  \Rightarrow x = \frac{a \pm b}{2}
$$

The two solutions ($\pm$) give you the two values for $x$:
\begin{align}
  x_A &= \frac{a + b}{2}\;,\; x_C = \frac{a - b}{2}
\end{align}

Substitute each solution for $x$ into the equation for $y$, to find the two associated values of $y$.
\begin{align}
  y_A &= \frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) + \frac{b^2-a^2}{2b} = \frac{a + b}{2}  \\
  y_C &= \frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) + \frac{b^2-a^2}{2b} = \frac{-a + b}{2}
\end{align}
Therefore points $A$ and $C$ are given by
\begin{align}
  A &= (x_A, y_A) = \left(\frac{a + b}{2} , \frac{a + b}{2}\right)  \\
  C &= (x_C, y_C) = \left(\frac{a - b}{2} , \frac{-a + b}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Looking at the interactive graph, the way we found $A$ and $C$ was to solve for the intersections between the circle centered at $M$ - which is the set of points at the same distance from $M$ as $B$ and $D$ - and the red line $g$ which is perpendicular to $\overline{BD}$ and which passes through $M$.

Comment: So you found the $2$ points intersecting that circle with the equation of the red line. But how did you find the equation of the circle?

Comment: A circle is the set of all points $(x, y)$ at a constant distance (the radius) from a single point (the center). We know the radius because $2r = \overline{BD}$ is the diameter. We know the center; it is $M$. So the equation for the circle is literally just the distance formula. Except that instead of knowing 2 points, we know 1 point and the distance, and solve for the other point.

Comment: In my answer, the first eqn (after "First, they lie along the line...") is the perpendicular line through M, and all the eqns of the 2nd eqn block (starts with "Second, the distance...") are equivalently for the circle. It's a little obfuscated, bc I was keeping algebra and fractions to a minimum, and I'm using the diameter instead of the radius. But if you move the $2$ (or $4$) in the first (or second) line over to the LHS, in both cases you get one of the canonical equations for a circle, $r = \sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}$, or $r^2 = (x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2$, for center $(x_0, y_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The point $M$ is $\frac{B+D}2=\left(\frac a2,\frac b2\right)$. You can obtain $A$ applying a rotation of $90^\circ$ to $D$ around $M$. So, you first compute $D-M=\left(-\frac a2,\frac b2\right)$. And then$$A=M+\left(-\frac b2,-\frac a2\right)=\left(\frac{a-b}2,\frac{b-a}2\right).$$By a similar argument,$$C=M+\left(\frac b2,\frac a2\right)=\left(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{a+b}2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Vectorially, the center of the square is

$$M=\frac{D+B}2$$ and the half diagonal is

$$H=\frac{D-B}2.$$

Now you rotate the half diagonal by $90°$, by means of

$$(H^\perp_x,H^\perp_y)=(H_y,-H_x).$$

Finally

$$C,A=M\pm H^\perp.$$

> $$\frac12(a\pm b,b\pm a).$$

Answer (score 0):

Map this onto the complex plane.

Suppose the point $x +yi$ is a point on the corner

then $x+ (y-b) i$ would be the path from $bi $ to $x+yi$

Multiplying by $i,$ will give this a 90 degree clockwise turn.

And adding this vector to $x+yi$ will get you to $a.$

$x+iy +  (x+ (y-b) i)i = a$

$x + yi + xi + b - y  = a$

$x-y = a-b\\
x+y = 0$

$x = \frac {a-b}{2}, y = \frac {b-a}{2}$  This is one corner.

The other is

$\frac {a}{2} + i\frac{b}{2} - (x+iy) = \frac {b}{2} + i \frac {a}{2}$

$(\frac b2, \frac a2)$

Okay so you don't want a smart ass doing complex analysis on a basic geometry problem.

Consider this figure:
[image]

The red triangle is congruent to the green triangle.

From the point $(\frac a2, \frac b2)$  move down $\frac {b}2$ units and left $\frac a2$ and you will be on a vertex. 
or from the center point, move up $\frac b2$ units, and right $\frac a2$ units, and you will be on the other vertex.